# Cannot find the object "digitalcamera" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a problem when I'm executing this query then this error occures:

```
Cannot find the object "digitalcamera" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

and my query is :

```
ALTER TABLE digitalcamera ADD lineimage image;
```

Comment: Side note: *"ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of MicrosoftSQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, ..."* See [ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993%28v=sql.100%29)

Answer (score 0):

Likely you are not part of the role DBO or DDLAdmin on the database.  Talk to your friendly DBA to see if he can your SQL Server user those permissions.  If he isn't comfortable giving you those roles see if he grant you alter table.  Other possibilities are you in the right database/server?  Does this table really exist?